# React Native Navigation - startTabBasedApp - only load tab if clicked on

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

When using [startTabBasedApp(params)](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=starttabbasedappparams) in [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) (by Wix), all of the tabs load at once.

Is there a way to make it so that only the initial tab loads? And then only after clicking on another tab does that tab load?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible. See [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/74#issuecomment-257074465) comment for more information, it seems like they intended this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use the following within the component:

```
onNavigatorEvent(event) {
  switch (event.id) {
    case "bottomTabSelected":
      this.setState({ didPressTab: true })
      break
    case "willAppear":
  ApplicationScreensManager.getInstance().registerCurrentActiveScreen(ApplicationScreens.WebViewContainerScreen)
     }
      break
  }
}
```

while this **case "bottomTabSelected":** is fired only when selecting a tab, then you can set the state raising a flag and only then do whatever you intended on when pressing the tab.

good luck